# How to handle bidirectional pin (inout) in a verilog task

Tags: task, verilog, bidirectional, inout

I want to use a bidirectional data bus in my controller.Here's the code

```
module controller ( clk, data_out);
// Port Declaration
input   clk;
inout   [7:0] data_out;

reg     [7:0] a;
reg     [7:0] b;
wire    [7:0] c;

// data should write to data_out (data_out act as output)

task write; 
input c;
begin

assign data_out = a;
data_out <= c;

end
endtask

// data should read from data_out (data_out act as input)

task read; 
output b;
begin

assign data_out = 8'bz;
b <= data_out;

end
endtask

endmodule
```

when I compile this i'm getting an error saying

> LHS in procedural continuous assignment may not be a net: data_out.

it's says there is an error in  `assign data_out = a;` and `assign data_out = 8'bz;` 
I know assign should be done in always or initial block but in a task using those blocks are useless/give eroor

Then, how we can change directions of the bus in side a task??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use assign in initial and always blocks. I don't get why you necessarily want it in task?
Simply use assign alone. Assinging value to bidirectional port needs a flag that specifies what action- read or write- should be done. Syntax is like:

```
  assign bidir_port = [flag] ? a : 1'bz;
```

Comment: *can't* should be replaced with ***shouldn't***. A procedural assign (assign inside always/initial) is currently legal though scheduled for deprecation. [IEEE1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) Annex C.4.2 "The procedural assign and deassign statements can be a source of design errors and can be an impediment to tool implementation. The procedural assign and deassign statements do not provide a capability that cannot be done by another method that avoids these problems. Therefore, the procedural assign and deassign statements are on a deprecation list."